# If torque is the driver of rotation, why doesn't more torque (rotational force) mean faster rotation?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

I got confused about the car. In most places they said that for acceleration when we start we need more torque (which is consistent with the fact that the highest acceleration is in first gear). But in that case, the torque is the highest, and on the other hand, the speed and number of revolutions of the wheel are the lowest ($P=T*w$). Also, how do we accelerate later (from 70 km/h to 80 km/h) if they say that then we need a smaller torque, but it is the torque that causes the angular acceleration similar to the force ( τ(⬆)=I*α(⬆) similar that F(⬆)=m*a(⬆)). Acceleration from 0 to 10 km/h is the same as from 70 to 80 and both should be caused by a force, but for the first we need a greater moment and for the second less and the moment is a force. There is chaos in my head right now and I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Torque provides rotational acceleration, meaning a change in rotational speed. It does not require any torque to maintain a particular rotational speed (in the absence of friction), regardless of how fast that rotation is. Torque is only required for changing rotational speed: the higher the torque the faster the rate of change of rotation.

> Acceleration from 0 to 10 km/h is the same as from 70 to 80

In typical cars it is not the same. Because of the different gears there is generally more torque for 0 to 10 than from 70 to 80. So the rate of change (acceleration) is greater at the lower speeds.